# What does "whole 360" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

In heist comedy movie *Logan Lucky (2017)*, Fish Bang said these words to Jimmy, who forced them to mount the heist a week earlier:

> Fish Bang: We needed a moral reason to pull this job with you. Now, we
> was fine with you wanting to get back at that store for messing with
> your hot sister. But you did a **whole 360** on everything when you moved
> up the date!

What does "whole 360" mean in this context?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

360 is the number of degrees in a circle, usually representing a complete, or 'whole' turn (hence "a whole 360").

There are a number of commonly used phrases that include '360' to denote a complete turn around.

Actually, I feel that a lot of such phrases are technically wrong. For example, I've seen "360 degree turn" used to mean a *change in direction*, similar to the phrase "a U-turn". But a turn in the opposite direction would only be 180 degrees - turning 360 degrees means you would end up facing the same direction you began with.

Given the context of your quote - moving a date *forward* - this seems like another example of it being an ill-fitting use of the term. That could be intentional on the part of the writers - scripts use everyday language, even if terms are being used incorrectly. It  seems that the character Fish Bang is referring to Jimmy *changing his mind*.

Comment: My guess is the speaker would have said *You did a **volte-face / U-turn / flip-flop** on everything* if he knew any of those, *and* had a bit more understanding of basic geometry! Otherwise we're being pushed towards interpreting it as something more akin to *For all your shilly-shallying, you've just ended up where you started!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree, though even the 360-degrees reading can be made sensible when you consider that people will get dizzy and disoriented if you suddenly spin them all the way around: they're still in the same place, facing the same direction, but they'll need to recover.

Comment: For what it's worth, a character in _The Last Action Hero_ uses the same "360 degrees" phrase to mean "about face" and is told it's actually 180 degrees.

Comment: Are they trying to imply the speaker isn't overly smart? "Doing a 180" is a common phrase in my opinion. I feel "doing a 360" implies someone who doesn't understand geometry and/or mangles common idioms.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth yes. Sam and Fish are the over-the-top comedic redneck characters in a film where all of the heroes are rednecks (but the rest of them are given a bit more dignity).

Comment: @NomadHill I've updated my answer in light of the added context. I still think it is an 'incorrect' use of such a term, but that might be deliberate and the meaning seems clear.

Answer (score 9):

The characters Sam and Fish say a lot of things, especially when they're angry or indignant, that the audience is meant to recognize as humorously wrong (for example "vagrant fliolation" instead of "flagrant violation").  This is a common way in film and TV to portray a character who *believes* themselves to be very smart, but who is actually quite stupid.

In this case, Fish means to say that Jimmy is "doing a 180" — which means reversing course (turning 180 degrees), or breaking a promise. But instead it comes out as "doing a 360", which is comedically inappropriate (since turning 360 degrees leaves you facing the same way you were originally).

Comment: This sounds very much like the classic Australian show "Kath and Kim". "Mum I don't want to be rich, I want to be effluent Mum, Effluent!"

Answer (score 0):

Broadly, "whole 360" was there used as though it meant "about turn" but that's diametrically opposed to reality.

"… a whole 360…" reads as though it implies completely changing your mind; asking for the exact opposite.

In fact, turning a "whole 360" on your lounge floor should show it actually means not "about…" ending with the opposite, but "complete…" ending exactly where you started.

"Whole 360" fails because the useful "about" turn - what political pundits love to call a "U turn"… is 180°, not 360°.

That's about arithmetic and semantics, not grammar or vocabulary.